# Can't save whole pictures Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-camera, android-gallery

I'm still fairly new to android development but I'm learning as I go and I'm taking a class to learn some more.  I've got an app that does a few things but the part I'm stuck on is dealing with the camera and taking photos.  The idea is that the app will either take a photo with the camera and set the image to be the "source" for an ImageView.  I can do this just fine if I use a bitmap for the ImageView.  However the user should also be able to import a photo from their gallery into the app after taking it with the camera and saving it.  This is where I'm stuck.  I've been following this tutorial on how to set it up and get it working but it's giving me a strange error.  https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

I was able to get up to and through the "Get the thumbnail" section but after that I get stuck. I'm not sure why it won't save my photo to any location.

There's code that says:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
```

and I realized that I needed to make a folder in my `res` folder called `xml` and put a file in there called `file_paths` which I did. and that's where I put

```
<Paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.android.postvu/files/pictures" />
</Paths>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

My (relevant) Java Code:

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException
    {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
        );
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    static final int REQUET_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent()
    {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        {
            File photoFile = null;
            try
            {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            { }

            if (photoFile != null)
            {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUET_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private void galleryAddPic()
    {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

My Manifest.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.postvu">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2">    </uses-feature>
                <uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So where is the error you mention on your title? post the logcat stacktrace relevant to the error. Plus in your code I can see that you are muting an exception, `IOException`: `catch (IOException ex) {}`. This is bad because if for some reason this exception is thrown you will never be informed! place a `Log.e("TAG", "error", ex)` inside your `catch` block. Most probably the error is there.

Comment: I'm sorry.  i forgot to change the title

Comment: Moreover why dont you download the sample application from the url you posted and see what you are doing differently and correct it. http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/PhotoIntentActivity.zip

Answer (score 0):

Crop or Camera activity doesn't have access on specified path.
You are launching Crop intent for cropping image, Its not in your application. But in file provider you specified inside your application path.

Answer (score 0):

`Storagedir` is different from the external path you mention in the xml file. Change to path=".".